# Multiple DHCP servers for two seperate domain on one vlan

Tags: dhcp, domain-controller, failover, domains

I would like to setup 3 DHCP servers for two domains so one will be failover for both. I have 2 DCs (AA, AB) in domain A and 1 DC (BB) in domain B. All three DCs are on the same vlan (192.168.1.XXX). I would like to setup:

AA - have scope `192.168.1.0 - 150`
BB - have scope `192.168.1.151 - 254`
BA - to be failover for both above servers.

Is it possible to do something like that? If not is there any other approach I can achieve so both domains will have enough redundancy and be able to run on the same vlan (if not other option will be to simply setup separate vlan for company B I think)